# How to use multiple Application Insights in single web page

Tags: jquery, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Azure Application Insights in my web application.
I want to track one type of event in first Application insights and second type of event in second Application Insights.

Is it possible to use two instrumentation key of Application Insights in one Page using Client side API?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What benefit do you get from separating?

Comment: Due to large number of data... I just want to know is this possible ? I tried but some how second instrumentation veritable call does not work for me

Comment: how/why doesn't it work?  you'd have to create 2 separate applicationInsights objects, each initialized with its own ikey, and then just send events with one or the other.

Comment: but it seems like just splitting your stuff in half is only going to fix your problem for a little while if you're sending too much data.  at some point you'll have 3 ikeys in one page?  then 4?  this doesn't seem like a very scalable long term idea.  how much data are you sending that you think you need to split it?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize 2 different Application Insights object based on 2 different keys & utilize them to track different telemetry.

```
//first object initialization
var appInsights1=window.appInsights1||function(config){
......
    instrumentationKey:"<key1>",
});

window.appInsights1 = appInsights1; //assigning to global variable
appInsights1.trackPageView();       //first object to track Pageview

//second object initialization
var appInsights2=window.appInsights2||function(config){
......
    instrumentationKey:"<key2>",
});

window.appInsights2 = appInsights2; //assigning to global variable
appInsights2.trackException(ex);    //second object to track Exception
```